# Updating mysql email field without affecting

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Recently I mass added customers details. However, my client just updated me that the email address format is wrong.

For example: The previous given email was `abc@mail.com`. However, I have to edit to this to `abc@me.mail.com`.

Is there any way I can check for `@mail.com` and change it to `@me.mail.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update your_table
set email = replace(email, '@mail.com', '@me.mail.com')
where email like '%@mail.com'
```